# Android Studio ужасно тормозит при редактировании разметки в редакторе и при ручном изменении XML

Tags: android-studio, xml

У меня нет никаких идей, как это решить. Визуальным редактором разметки стало невозможно пользоваться: я выбрал View-элемент, а панель Attributes показывает его атрибуты только через минуты две. Редактирование XML вручную также дико тормозит.